# How can I change the product image size from square to rectangle in big cartel Luna Theme

Tags: image-size

How can I change the product image size in the new Luna theme from square to rectangle 223 px x 330 px - it was possible in the old version - but can't find where to change it in the new one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.